# Is there a way to configure Thunderbird with malicious IP DB to flag incoming mails as spam?

Tags: thunderbird, database, spam-prevention

I checked a spam mail source and noticed it could come from a malicious server. I saw there are some malicious IP DB like [AbuseIPDB](https://www.abuseipdb.com/) collecting such IPs.

Is there a way to let Thunderbird check the IPs with AbuseIPDB or any database like does [fail2ban](https://www.abuseipdb.com/fail2ban.html) for example to flag mails from such source as spam?

Comment: Note that thunderbird is only a SMTP/POP3/IMAP client and cannot reject an incoming mail, but only move or flag it based on a ruleset. If you want to reject emails, you need to implement it in your mailserver.

Comment: @mashuptwice, correct, replaced reject by mark.

Comment: @mashuptwice This is not accurate. Thunderbird has a built-in learning spam filter that does not rely on the mail server.

Comment: @DanielB, I think they mean "reject" at "server step".

Comment: @DanielB my point stands correct. Under "reject" one would understand "refuse to deliver" and usually inform the sender about the incident.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this behaviour is typically implemented by Mail Transfer Agents (MTAs) prior to the email being received by a Mail User Agent (MUA) like Thunderbird. The MTA will inspect email and score it appropriately, at which point it can be rejected, marked as spam, etc. [SpamAssassin](https://spamassassin.apache.org/) is one such tool that MTAs use, though there are many others. And finally, various large Email Service Providers (ESPs) also have their own bespoke spam-detection methods.

In general, spam is a persistent enough, and difficult enough, problem that attempting to tackle it entirely locally at the MUA level is (in my opinion) a losing battle.

But since you're specifically speaking of performing such filtering at the MUA level, directly within Thunderbird, then **no**, there is not currently such a feature in Thunderbird. There is an extensive filtering system available, and there is a (bayesian, I think) spam filtering system within Thunderbird, but no automatic way to flag emails from specific IP addresses as spam. In theory, one could inspect specific email headers that may have such data, and craft filters that label or move emails with matching IP address strings, but that would be a manual process.